# Extrapolating raster to specific area?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, extents, extrapolation

Can I extrapolate a raster with the extent of North America (current geography) to the shape of the continent during the Last Glacial Maximum?

I would want to extrapolate pH-values to the additional coastline areas present in the LGM that currently are under water.